# Git clone doesn't download all the files due to windows limit on length of file path

Tags: git, github, windows-7-x64

I am trying to clone a Git repo on windows 7. But git is not cloning all the files. I have checked the repo and there are no submodules so adding **`--recursive`** flag is also not helpful.

IMO the reason for above mentioned behavior is [windows limit on file path upto 255 characters.](https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_personal/search_long_paths.shtml)

Is there a way to resolve this issue from client side(Windows) as I don't have access to restructure the repo. as per my requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had yesterday the same problem as you (on win10) :)
Just modify your git config:

```
core.longpaths=true
```

Should work